# Popover (set to close on click outside) closes immediately when auto focus on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover

I don't know how to properly set up my popover so that when you click on "New" this opens the popover and the focus shifts to the input field without popover auto-closing. Also, as you can see the popover can be closed by clicking anywhere on the document.

When you click on "New" you can see for a split second the input field gets focused, but then the whole thing closes.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
      html: true,
      sanitize: false,
      trigger: 'focus',
      placement: "bottom",
      content: '<input id="newboard" class="card subtask-lb bg-dark text-light" type="text" placeholder="Enter new Board" />'
    }

    $('#input-index').popover(options).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
      $('#newboard').focus();
    });
  })
```

```html
<a tabindex="0" id="input-index" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
  New
</a>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reeson46/fyos8dak/9/)

**UPDATE**:
Someone posted a solution and then short after deleted it, but I've managed to copied it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = {
    html: true,
    sanitize: false,
    placement: "bottom",
    content: '<input id="newboard" class="card subtask-lb bg-dark text-light" type="text" placeholder="Enter new Board" />'
  }

  $('#input-index').popover(options).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    $('#newboard').focus();
  });
});

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#input-index').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(this).popover('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: try remove `trigger: 'focus'`

Comment: I tried that before, and it works this way, but then I lose the "click anywhere else to close"...